# Can't add a web port in BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm trying to invoke a web-service from a BizTalk orchestration - I create the reference to the web-service's WSDL, then try to wire up a port, but an existing port type isn't showing up. Looking at BT 2010's known issues, I find:

*When Add Web reference in Design Tools does not show port type in BizTalk Orchestration Designer 
The unexpected behavior in BizTalk Design tools is due to a known limitation of Visual Studio 2010.
Workaround: You need to install QFE patch for Visual Studio 2010 to fix this issue.*

But I can't seem to find an actual link to this QFE. Anyone?

(And yes, I know you can use the Generated Items Wizard to accomplish this differently, but in this case I'm specifically looking for this fix)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm sure you did, I checked through all of the BizTalk 2010 Cumulative Updates ([1 thru. 5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555976)) and found no mention of this issue. I also found mention of your issue on Sandro Pereira's blog post which appears to be re-hash of the [BizTalk Server 2010 Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/F/0FFEF5D0-BE04-4D03-9125-75B8AD243E57/Readme.htm) (at which point I ask myself where is the value in re-posting this sort of detail...)

I finally checked the [MSDN Archive](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Visual%20Studio%202010) for details of VS QFE fixes around this issue, but no luck.

I think you're next best step is to contact MS and raise a support call - I wouldn't imagine this will be chargeable given that the documentation is clearly lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads

It contains all QFE fixes for Visual Studio

Answer (score -1):

There is a special tools to do the Web-service from orchestration in BizTalk. Do not use the Add Web Reference or Add Service command!
Go to the Start / BizTalk Server / BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard. When you finish with it, you will get a Web service in IIS wich expose the receive ports of the orchestration.
It is possible to create the WS without orchestration. In this case you have to choose the "Publish schemas as WCF service" option in this wizard. There are a lot of blogs and good articles in MSDN BizTalk Help about this wizard.

Comment: The OP is asking how he should consume a web-service, not expose a BizTalk Orchestration or Schema as a web-service.